# How to check game board status in my tkinter game?

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I am currently making a 2 player tic-tac-toe game with tkinter, however as of now I don't know how I could check if the board had a winning situation or when to tell the victor they have won.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
twod = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]  # 0 will be blank 1 will be circle 2 will be x
rows = 0
columns = 0
types = "X"

for x in twod:   
    for y in x:
        butt = Button(text=' ', width=20, height=10)
        twod[columns][rows]= butt
        butt.config(text=' ', width=20, height=10, command=lambda butt=butt : click(butt)) 
               
        butt.grid(row=rows, column=columns)
        columns += 1
    rows += 1
    columns = 0
root.mainloop()
```

I have deleted a few functions in there as those aren't the problem, the main problem is the control flow.

My first step is to try and check across however I have no idea where I should place it in my code.

So, to summarize my problem, there is a `mainloop` function in Tkinter that should be looping through the entire code. However, everything I type in there i.e. `print` statements, only gets executed once.

Comment: Everything in a tkinter application pretty much has to happen _while_ `mainloop()` is running. In this case it seems like you could just check the board's status after a move gets made by a player — since that the only time it changes. If it's a winning more, you can change what the being displayed by the GUI (i.e. pop-up one of the [`tkinter.messagebox`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524020423id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html) dialogs).

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, however, it seems as if nothing gets updated. I'm slightly confused about the control flow as to where I should check it. I want to make my code run as long as the board isn't filled. that is why I am returning a true or false statement.Also I just don't know where to place that code, like I have no idea where the player makes a move

Comment: One approach would be to make the game board a 2D list—a list of `Button` lists—with each attached to a callback (`command`) function that updated the board at that particular position in the list-of-lists accordingly. This same function could also check to see if the move wins the game (and displays the appropriate message box if so). Tkinter apps are what is called user-event-driven, meaning the everything they do is in respond to some kind of user input (such as clicking on a `Button` and invoking its callback function).

Comment: However, how would I leave the program once a certain condition is met since it is all based on button checks

Comment: You can exit the `mainloop()` by calling the universal widget `quit()` method. i.e. `root.quit()`. This will return to where it (`mainloop`) was called — likely the last line of the script. In this scenario, the call to `quit()` could occur where the status check is done.

Comment: You could also use `Label`s instead of `Button`s for the board positions. See for example [Creating a game board with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349526/creating-a-game-board-with-tkinter).

Answer (score 0):

As @martineau suggested, you can check the board after the button click. You can use binary patterns to check for a winner.

Try this code. It fills the board with random values then checks for a win when you click a button.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
twod = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]  # 0 will be blank 1 will be circle 2 will be x
rows = 0
columns = 0
types = "X"

btnlst = []

def CheckWin():
  wins = [0b111000000,0b000111000,0b000000111,0b100010001,0b001010100,0b100100100,0b010010010,0b001001001]  # all possible win patterns
  for p in ['X','O']:  # check each player
     m = int("".join(['1' if b['text'] == p else '0' for b in btnlst]),2) # merge button values into single binary value
     for w in wins: # check each pattern
        if w & m == w:  # if pattern matches  (binary and)
           print(p, 'wins')
           return
  print('No Winner')
  
def click(evt):
  CheckWin()

for x in twod:   
    for y in x:
        butt = Button(text=' ', width=20, height=10)
        twod[columns][rows]= butt
        butt.config(text=random.choice(['X','O']), width=20, height=10, command=lambda butt=butt : click(butt)) 
               
        butt.grid(row=rows, column=columns)
        btnlst.append( butt)
        columns += 1
    rows += 1
    columns = 0
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you maybe send me a source as to where I could learn more on binary patterns

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation